# Calling the method of class with unidentified type

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, void

I have a class named `MyClass` that is subscribed by another class. When some events happen, `MyClass` should notify subscribers. 
I'm trying to use template for the subscriber's type. Because I don't want to let others(who are in charge of subscriber class) need to care about modifying `MyClass` for subscribing. 
So I've written codes below,

```
class MyClass {

public:

    template<typename T>
    void subscribeEvents(const T &controller)
    {
        m_subscriber = static_cast<T*>(m_subscriber);
        m_subscriber = &controller;
    }

    void notifyPositionChanged(const long &position) const {

          (m_subscriber)->onPositionChanged(position);
    }

private:

    void m_subscriber;  // will be changed to array or something else

}
```

Actually the `controller` object has a method named`onPositionChanged`.

But as you know, it's not compiled for this line.

```
(m_subscriber)->onPositionChanged(position);
```

Now I understand why it's an error, but the problem is that I don't know how to modify codes or change my design. Please let me know what I'm missing and misunderstanding. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use template for this. Just use a base class for your subscribers. And MyClass operate on your base class

```
class ISubscribe {
public:
    virtual void onPositionChanged(const long &position) = 0;
};

class MyClass {
public:

    void subscribeEvents(ISubscribe *controller)
    {
        m_subscriber = controller;
    }

    void notifyPositionChanged(const long &position) const {

      (m_subscriber)->onPositionChanged(position);
    }
private:

    ISubscribe *m_subscriber;  // will be changed to array or something else
};

class SampleSubscriber : public ISubscribe {
public :
    void onPositionChanged(const long &position) override{
              ...
    }
};

void main() {
    SampleSubscriber s;
    MyClass m;

    m.subscribeEvents(&s);
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a common interface to all your subscribers, then use this interface as m_subscriber's type. Savagely casting whatever parameter you receive to a defined type will lead only to undefined behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I think I should keep in mind the savage casting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::function`:

```
class MyClass {
public:

    template<typename CALLBACK>
    void subscribeEvents(CALLBACK &&controller)
    {
        m_subscriber = std::forward<CALLBACK>(controller);
    }

    void notifyPositionChanged(const long &position) const
    {
        if (m_subscriber)
            m_subscriber(position);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(const long&)> m_subscriber;
}
```

This gives the subscriber full freedom of what it wants to subscribe. For example:

```
there.subscribeEvents([this](const long &pos) { handlePosChange(pos); }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I will try to adapt your way later. I'm not familiar with std::fuction yet. I need to study more.